# Read Json message from Kafka Topic using pyspark

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to read a json message from kafka topic using spark streaming using a custom schema, I can see data is coming when I am using Cast value as string only. But when I am using a schema it is not working.
Data is like this :

```
|{"items": [{"SKU": "22673", "title": "FRENCH GARDEN SIGN BLUE METAL", "unit_price": 1.25, "quantity":   6}, {"SKU": "20972", "title": "PINK CREAM FELT CRAFT TRINKET BOX ", "unit_price": 1.25, "quantity": 2},   {"SKU": "84596F", "title": "SMALL MARSHMALLOWS PINK BOWL", "unit_price": 0.42, "quantity": 1}, {"SKU":   "21181", "title": "PLEASE ONE PERSON METAL SIGN", "unit_price": 2.1, "quantity": 12}], "type": "ORDER",  "country": "United Kingdom", "invoice_no": 154132552854862, "timestamp": "2023-01-20 07:34:22"}
|
```

I have used schema as :

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("items", StructType([
        StructField("SKU", IntegerType(), True), 
        StructField("title", StringType(), True), 
        StructField("unit_price", FloatType(), True), 
        StructField("quantity", IntegerType(), True)
    ]), True)
    StructField("type", StringType(), True),
    StructField("country", StringType(), True), 
    StructField("invoice_no", StringType(), True), 
    StructField("timestamp", TimestampType(), True)
    ])
```

I am using the function :

```
kafkaDF = lines.selectExpr('CAST(value AS STRING)').select(from_json('value',schema).alias("value")).select("value.items.SKU","value.items.title","value.items.unit_price","value.items.quantity","value.type","value.country","value.invoice_no","value.timestamp")
```

Still the output are coming as null.

Answer (score 0):

It's null because the schema is incorrect.

Your `items` need to be an `ArrayType`, containing your defined `StructType`

That being said, you cannot select `value.items.X` since there isn't a single element there. You'd need to `EXPLODE(value.items)` first.

Comment: Thank you for correcting, please can you share what code I need to write ?

Comment: You basically already have it. Just add an ArrayType. `StructField("items", ArrayType(StructType([..])), StructField("type", ...), ...`